# Meaning of "she lives 10 minutes away"

Tags: meaning

I want to know what

> she lives 10 minutes away

means.

Can we say instead that she would be here 10 minutes ago?

Comment: It means it would take ten minutes to travel from where she lives to some  reference point which is not expressed in your sentence but understood from the discourse context. You could define that reference point with a *from* PP: "She lives ten minutes away *from here*." (You could also omit the *away* if the reference point is defined: "She lives ten minutes from here".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not meant by it. It means that it takes 10 minutes from a place (usually 'here', but it could be another place discussed before) to get to her house. The mode of travel (walking, driving) is not specified but is usually clear from the context.

Comment: @ Dear Glorfindel, thanks your respond. I wan find a possible question to"No, she doesnot. She lives an hour away" my answer is "Does she live near here?"

Comment: Yes, that would be a plausible question and answer.